# yii2 select2 by kartik-v set default value

Tags: php, yii2

I've a question about yii2 kartik-v widget select 2.

the widget is attached to a field in my view

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'address')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Inserta an address '],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 3,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => Url::to(['register/addresses']),
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
        ],
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(address) { return address.name; }'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (address) { return address.name; }'),
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "select2:select" => "function(e) {
                      // some function

                }",
    ],
]);
?>
```

if in my controller i want to set to this field a value

like: `$model->address = "Some Value";` on the view the field remain blank

what can i do?

**UPDATE!**

As the documentation say i can use the option: 'initValueText' if i use the ajax version of this plugin. So i've tried to set `'initValueText' => $model->address,` but the result is the same

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widgets/issues/87

Comment: I've tried but all i've got is the blank field with a cross (for delete the selection) on the right

Answer (score 2):

hey i had the same issue with #ajax neither placeholder nor initValueText were showing 
what i did was this

```
<?php
    $product = $model->product_id ? Product::findOne($model->product_id)->name : 'select ....';
    echo $form->field($model, 'product_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'initValueText' => $product, // set the initial display text
        // 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'select ....'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'minimumInputLength' => 3,
            'ajax' => [
                'url' => Url::to(['list']),
                'dataType' => 'json',
                'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
            ],
            'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
            'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(product_id) { return product_id.name; }'),
            'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (product_id) { return product_id.name; }'),
        ],
    ]);?>
```

if the model is new 'select ....' is shown else the product's name
since "options" is not doing much either
hope this will be hopeful to someone

Answer (score 1):

The problem was this:

```
  'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
  'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(address) { return address.name; }'),
  'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (address) { return address.name; }'),
```

It seems that this plugin want a specific return for the keys 'templateResult' and 'templateSelection'.

I've modified the JsExpression return value with address.text (instead of adress.name) as the guide examples : [Link](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2).

And then i've modified also the PHP method that return the results:

```
public function actionAddresses($q = NULL, $id = NULL)
{

    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    $results = array();
    if (!is_null($q)) {

        $geocoder = new GeocodingClient();
        $request = $geocoder->lookup(['address' => $q]);
        $counter = 1;
        foreach ($request['results'] as $key => $value) {
            $results['results'][] = [
                'id' => $counter,
                'text' => $value['formatted_address'], // Instead of 'name'
                'coordinate' => $value['geometry']['location']
            ];
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

I hope this may help someone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its bit late.. but i too had same problem.. i resolved it by assigning value

```
  <?=
  $form->field($model, 'address')->widget(Select2::className(), [
                          'initValueText' => $model->address,
                           'value' => $model->address,
                           'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Inserta an address '],
                           'pluginOptions' => [
                                    'allowClear' => true,
                                    'minimumInputLength' => 3,
                                'ajax' => [
                                    'url' => Url::to(['register/addresses']),
                                    'dataType' => 'json',
                                    'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
    ],
    'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
    'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(address) { return address.name; }'),
    'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (address) { return address.name; }'),
],
'pluginEvents' => [
    "select2:select" => "function(e) {
                  // some function

            }",
],
   ]);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you use kartik select2, in controller you have set a value (id/ids) and name values for 'initValueText'

```
$model->id = 1; // or if arrays [1,3,4,5]
$username = User::find()->select('name')->where('id' => $model->id)->scalar();
```

and in view kartik select2

```
$form->field($model, 'username')->widget(Select2::className(), [
'initValueText' => $username;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. Then I tried value key into the options and it worked.

```
<?php
 echo $form->field($model, 'test')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                                    //'data' => ['test', 'test2'],
                                    'initValueText'=>['test','test2'],
                                    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'value'=>['1','2']],
                                    'pluginOptions' => [
                                        'multiple' => true,
                                        'allowClear' => true,
                                        'minimumInputLength' => 1,
                                        'language' => [
                                            'errorLoading' => new JsExpression("function () { return 'Waiting for results...'; }"),
                                        ],
                                        'ajax' => [
                                            'url' => '...',
                                            'dataType' => 'json',
                                            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
                                        ],
                                        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (m) { return m; }') 
                                ?>
```

Hope It'll be helpful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

I fix this solution by using trigger function. In below method we can set default value in kartik select2 widget.

```
$('#id').val(11).trigger('change'); //in val() mention the hash value of your select2 list
```