# Select2 initial value doesn't appear

Tags: php, yii2

I Want to select value base on $_GET if exists soon.

Here is my code in view

```
<?php
      /*if ($model->isNewRecord && !isset($model->agent_id_upper)) {
         $model->agent_id_upper = 65;
       } not working too*/ 

        //$model->agent_id_upper = 65; ->not working
        echo Select2::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'name' => 'TbAgent[agent_id_upper]',
            //'id' => 'to_id',
            'initValueText' => '', // this only for ajax
            'data' => $data,
            'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Choose Agent ...',
            'multiple' => false,
            //'selected' => 65, -> not working
            //'value' => 65, -> not working
            'class' => ''
            ],
            ]
);
?>
```

65 is ID of record, If selected then it should show username of thus ID.

But my problem is username of 65 is not selected, it only show place holder.

How I can fix this? and Please give me references.

already read this

[yii2 select2 by kartik-v set default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627490/yii2-select2-by-kartik-v-set-default-value)

[Yii2: Kartik Select2: Initial Value from Model Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367212/yii2-kartik-select2-initial-value-from-model-attribute)

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/52278-kartik-select2-not-select-corretly/

but no luck with above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this? value is not inside options

```
<?= Select2::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'name' => 'id',
    'data' => $data,
    'value' => 65,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Choose Agent ...',
        'multiple' => false,
    ]
]) ?>
```